# Getting a routing error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a form to upload the image in Rails Project, the image is getting stored in the **storage** folder:

```
storage/system/development/racebooks/coverpictures/000/000/011/original/d4a1c1de8734feb430e4812891c8cd8901c13cc5
```

but when I try to get this image then I get the following error

```
production.log:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/storage/system/production/racebooks/coverpictures/000/000/011/original/d4a1c1de8734feb430e4812891c8cd8901c13cc5")
```

The folder should change depending on the environment, but then why I am getting this error?

**Update:** here is the code where I set path to upload image:

```
# Store uploaded files in $RAILS_ROOT/storage instead of public directory
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":rails_root/storage:url"
```

Note: I am using Paperclip.

Comment: It is storing it in the development directory but trying to fetch it from production

Comment: Are you using paperclip or carrierwave? For the route to work, the image would need to be uploaded in the `public/storage...` directory of the project.

Comment: @RSB yes it is, but the folder must change depending on the environment, but i think it is not getting changed, what's the solution then?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are setting the path

Comment: As @RSB and @codyeatworld says you have to upload an image in `public` directory and if you have uploaded an image when your app was running in `development` mode and now you are trying to fetch image in `production` mode then it will not match the URL as you are facing an issue.

Comment: @RSB ok here is the code:
# Stored uploaded files in $RAILS_ROOT/storage instead of public directory
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":rails_root/storage:url"